# ctype Linux so library Pointer TypeError

Tags: python, arguments, function-pointers, ctypes

I'm loading a C library (`.so` file) with `ctypes`. Then I'm setting arguments and calling one function and got the error below;

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ushort instance instead of _ctypes.PyCSimpleType
```

As I guess it is related to the POINTER definition at the end of 3rd line. Can you help?

```
import ctypes
mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfocas32.so')
mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3.argtypes = ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_ushort, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort)
mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3.restype = ctypes.c_long
h = ctypes.c_ushort
ret = mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3('192.168.1.1',9000,1,(h))
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) `h` must receive an instance of the type `c_ushort`, therefore:

```
h = ctypes.c_ushort()
```

(2) Assuming that the pointer to `h` is only used during the function call and shouldn't be stored longer, use

```
ret = mylib.cnc_allclibhndl3('192.168.1.1',9000,1,ctypes.byref(h))
```

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and got this error now: TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'

Comment: @Semih I oversaw another problem in your code. Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Now code runs until ret=mylib.cnc.... line then program suddenly terminates without any message. I've put this part in to try - exception error block nothing returns and code terminates at this line under try. Oopps :(

Comment: @Semih According to [this](https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/handle/cnc_allclibhndl3) the first parameter is a normal `char` pointer, not `wchar` pointer and the return type a (signed) `short`.

Comment: @Semih ... and it is declared with `WINAPI`, therefore don't use `ctypes.cdll` but `ctypes.windll`.

Comment: first of all thanks for your support. I've changed first parameter's type from wchar to char and run code, I've got "Error : argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type" . Then I revoked, now no error message appears. And as you wrote this library declarations are coded with WINAPI but I'm working on a Raspberry Arm Linux platform. So company released a linux version of this library (.so file), I'm using this file, as I've searched in this platform I can't call dll's by WINAPI.

Comment: I've examined company's linux library document and found  that I have to call cnc_startupprocess function before allclibhndl. I tried and now it works but I can't connect to specied IP address. It returns -16 means no connection but when I try to connect the same IP and port via telnet I can connect. So pyhsical and port connection is ready but code does not connect. I'm stuck.

Comment: @Semih This is probably a library-specific problem therefore I can't help you.